# C# Combo Box Data Sort

Tags: c#, sorting, combobox

I'm using a DataTable as the datasource for my ComboBox and I need to sort the Data into a strict order. The problem is that the I don't need in Ascending Order or Descending, it's how the customer see's the items as a priority, so there's not really any logic too it.

Will I need to create a column that has an ordering value and then sort the data by that column? I'm just looking for the best way to do this. In time, more items may be added and the ordering may need to change. This is something i want to achieve without hard coding each time.

The Data at present only has two columns, which look like below:-

> ApplicationName | ApplicationType

I just need the best way of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I would add a integer column to sort by, and let the user change the values. I assume the contents of the datatable are stored/serialised somewhere else when your application is closed, and this new column can be stored with it?

Comment: Yes, It will be in a  back-end database. Thanks, it something ive not had to do in the past, you learn something new everyday i suppose. :-)

Comment: Are you populating the datatable from the DB?